# c# Putting chart's title in a string variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm using c#, how do I put the title of a chart in a string variable?

I'm using a delegate so here is my code:

```
private void ChartTitle(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Chart Chart = (Chart)sender;
    string title=Chart.Titles. ???
}
```

Comment: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET WebForms, UWP?

Comment: what does `string title=Chart.Titles. ???` means ...

Comment: And for whichever framework... Have you looked in the documentation?... First step

Comment: i'm using winform, with string title=Chart.Titles. ??? i mean i don't know wich is the command line i have to insert!!

Answer (score 0):

As [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456641.aspx) says, you should add a title this way:

```
Chart1.Titles.Add("My Chart"); // Titles text, not the name
Chart1.Titles.["Title1"].Name = "MyTitle"; // By default charts titles name is Title1, we rename it
```

---

Then you could get the value with:

```
string title = Chart1.Titles["MyTitle"].Text;
```

Comment: in the main form i make a chart, then i use the delegate, inside i have to get the title's name, i can't use string title = Chart1.Titles["MyTitle"].Text; i can't use this cause actually i don't have "MyTitle", but i have to find it woth some method of chart i think

Comment: So that's why you need to create one when you initialize you chart, otherwhise is not possible to access an element that does not exist.